# Css - achieving 360 deg icon rotate in 2 clicks

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm using react and I have a button, when the button is clicked I want to rotate it by 180 deg, and when its clicked again, to rotate it again by 180 deg.
What I've managed to do is rotate it at the first time by 180, and in the second time by-180 deg.

jsx:

```
export default class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    render () {
        let classes = 'icon';
        if (this.props.isSelected) {
            classes += ' selected';
        }

        return (
            <IconButton className={classes}>expand_more</IconButton>
        )
    }
}
```

css:

```
.icon {
    transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4,0,.6,0);
}

.icon.selected {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

How can I achieve that in the best way?

Answer (score 2):

By using a `transition` on the default state and an `animation` on the selected state, you can achieve the effect:

```
.icon {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition: 300ms transform;
}

.icon.selected {
    animation: spin 300ms;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://codepen.io/trys/pen/9b527d6631b424ae11dc59588dab155d for a working demo

Comment: it doesnts work, the first animation is fine but at the seccond click, just the text rotates

Comment: Yeah, just noticed. Works fine on Firefox, doesn't on Chrome. I'll have a look into that now

Answer (score 0):

I found that (at least in react-native) the CSS needed to rotate an element is defined as:

```
transform: [{rotate: '360deg'}]
```